# spring project result of query group by 2 columns

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

using spring data jpa with spring boot I have a case where the native query result will be like this using group by (2 columns):

```
a | 1
a | 2
a | 3
b | 4 
b | 6
...
```

the second column is a primary key for another table lets say "A", my question is:
can I project the result to new interface like this:

```java
publice interface anInterface{
   String getColUmnA();
   List<A> getColumnB()
}
```

where first I have object contains first string and aggregate the second values as list of objects fetch by it is id.

Comment: what's the relation of two tables you have ?

Comment: this the final native query result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly you are looking for. The term "aggregation" suggests this is about SQL aggregations, but it seems you only want to do a simple projection of a collection.

AFAIK Spring Data Projections does not support JPQL/SQL aggregations or collection projections, so you can't directly do this. However, this is a perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage).

Blaze-Persistence is a query builder on top of JPA which supports many of the advanced DBMS features on top of the JPA model. I created Entity Views on top of it to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model. Since the attribute name is used as default mapping, you mostly don't need explicit mappings as 80% of the use cases is to have DTOs that are a subset of the entity model.

Assuming you have an entity model like this

```
@Entity
public class A {
    @Id
    String id;
    List<B> bs;
}

@Entity
public class B {
    @Id
    Integer id;
}
```

A projection with Entity Views could look as simple as the following

```
@EntityView(A.class)
interface AProjection {
    @IdMapping
    String getId();
    List<BProjection> getBs();
}
@EntityView(B.class)
interface BProjection {
    Integer getId();
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`AProjection dto = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, AProjection.class, id);`

But the Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

It will only fetch the mappings that you tell it to fetch